# The usage of "shall"

Tags: grammar, usage

> "Shall you have the chance to come to China, please feel free to
> contact us."

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: '_Should_ you have the chance' (meaning 'if you should') us the correct tense.

Answer (score 1):

The correct sentence should be "If you have the chance to come to China, please feel free to contact us."

They talk about the case when you have a chance to come to China, which you might not have. Which is why the sentence should begin with "If".